# Simple rechart not displaying bar even though the context option shows correctly

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I have a Recharts bar which works well but when I use my data (via a promise) the context displays the correct values but the chart doesn't display the bars strangely.  I'm learning React so not sure where the problem.  The code included is within the componentDidMount event.

Any help much appreciated.  Many thanks

**Chart code**

```
<div className="col">
<ResponsiveContainer>
 <BarChart
    data={this.state.chartData}
    margin={{ top: 20, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 5 }} >
    <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="0" />
    <XAxis dataKey="name" />
    <YAxis />
    <Tooltip />
    <Bar dataKey="total" stackId="a" fill="blue" />
 </BarChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
</div>
```

**Chrome console panel**

self is just var self = this

[image: Chrome console panel highlighting data is there]

**Screen shot of empty chart**

Note the context dialog is as expected (showing total = 5)

[image: Screen shot showing chart]

Comment: Can you provide with a codesandbox?

Comment: tricky, I'll try but I'm not sure if I can

Comment: Weirdly if I browse around the site and then navigate to the page with the chart it works.  Any ideas what that could be?  If I sit on the chart page and hit refresh it doesn't display the bar but if I just browse around and come back it displays the bar.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the same problem.